# Solving an inequality with $\sqrt{\log(x)/ x}$ and $\log(x)/ x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am looking for a simpler version of the following inequality:

$\sqrt{\log(x)/ 2x}$ +$3\log(x)/ x-a\le 0$

$x$ is a variable and $a$ is constant ($0<a\le 0.1$).

Generally, is there any facts that reduces $\sqrt{c_1\log(x)/x}$ +$c_2\log(x)/ x$ to a simpler version ($c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants)?

Thanks

Comment: yes; define $t = \frac{\log x}{x}$ and conclude things about $t,$

Comment: @WillJagy: Could you please elaborate it more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints: Define $$y = \sqrt{\frac{\log x}{x}}$$ then the inequality becomes

$$\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}} + 3y^2 - a\leq 0$$
or equivalently
$$3\left(y + \frac{1}{6\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 \leq a + \frac{1}{24}$$

Now solve for the range of $y$ for which this is satisfied. Then solve for $x$, but remember that we must have $x\geq 1 \to y\geq 0$ in order for $y$ to be well-defined (since $\log x < 0$ for $0<x<1$ and the square root of a negative number is no good).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Could you please tell me how to find the range of $x$ after finding the range of $y$ (say $y\le \overline{y}$)? In other words, $\log(x)\le x \overline{y}$.

Comment: @ElrondGimli This becomes a numerical problem as $\frac{\log x}{x}$ does not have a (useful) analytical inverse. However, in this case I think you will be dealing with small numbers $\overline{y} \ll 1$ so writing $x = 1 + \delta$ and using $\log(x) = \log(1+\delta) \approx \delta$ gives $\frac{\log x}{x} \approx \delta$ to first order in $\delta$ so $1\leq  x = 1 + \delta \lesssim 1 + \overline{y}$ should be a decent approximation.

Comment: Is there any other range of answers for larger values of $x$ (say $x$>2)? Is there any lower bound for $x$ in that case?

Comment: @ElrondGimli Yes there is. $\frac{\log x}{x}$ is increasing until $x=e$ and then decreasing so if $\overline{y} \leq e^{-1}$ then there is an $x_*$ s.t. $\frac{\log x}{x} \leq \overline{y}$ for all $x\geq x_*$. Finding the analytical approximation is harder, I would reccomend doing it numerically if I were you...or if you want an analytical expression you can express the solution in terms of the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) as $x_* = e^{-W(-\overline{y})}$.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. So, the easiest way to find the intersection points of $f(x)=\frac{\log(x)}{x}$, $x\ge1$ and $g(x)=c$, $c\le e^{-1}$ is to use a numerical approach, right?